# Center align ion-title

Tags: css, ionic-framework

[image]

In the following image the ion-title painting is not properly aligned at the center,How to align at the exact center

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>

<ion-navbar>
<ion-title> <p align="center" style="color:white;">{{service.name}}</p>
</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Comment: The title is shifting because of your back button. Fixing that will fix it too.

Comment: `margin-left: -48px;` adjusts for this and the hamburger.

Answer (score 40):

Ionic CSS attributes are deprecated.

Replace:

```
'<ion-title text-center>'
```

With:

```
'<ion-title class="ion-text-center">'
```

Comment: If there was a hamburger or back icon in the top left, this would center within the remaining width rather than center of the viewport which is what the OP desires.

Answer (score 19):

just add ***text-center*** attribute to your ***ion-navbar*** tag or ***ion-title*** tag, like this:

```
<ion-navbar text-center>
  <ion-title>
    Some text...
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

or

```
<ion-navbar>
  <ion-title text-center>
    Some text...
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

Answer (score 8):

I just had this happen in our app / converting from Ionic3 -> Ionic6, and it bothered me that none of the answers really seemed to understand that (in the OP's example) 'Painting' should be centered in the center of the app / screen, NOT centered in the remaining space not taken up by whatever buttons/text may or may not exist in slot="start" or slot="end".

This isn't perfect, but it works nicely.

```
ion-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This should be the accepted answer by far. I mean, the image is right there...

Answer (score 3):

```
<ion-title text-center>
    <p class="centered-p">Title</p>
</ion-title>

.md .centered-p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -15%
}
```

it is not perfect but working fine for me in both android & IOS

Comment: This works for small screens, but will break at wider resolutions where 15% is much greater than then 32 or so pixels that the icon takes up.

Answer (score 0):

In scss of your page paste the following code:

`ion-title { text-align: center !important; }`

It worked for me.